# VPN setup on mikrotik router

Tags: vpn, routing, pptp, mikrotik

I have successfully setup a pptp vpn server on a Mikrotik routerboard. I am able to connect to the VPN and can successfully access a certain IP range.

This is my setup:

ADSL modem/router - mikrotik router -> private community network (CTWUG)

IP range at home is a subset of the larger CTWUG network range : 172.18.107.224/28
The CTWUG network rage : 172.18.0.0/16

- In my home setup the mikrotik router acts as the gateway and router.
  IP: 172.18.107.238
- The ADSL router acts as the DHCP server. IP :
    172.18.107.237
- There is a route on the mikrotik for access to the CTWUG range:
  172.18.0.0/16 -> 172.18.107.252
- And a route for internet    access 0.0.0.0/0 -> 172.18.107.237 (ADSL
  modem)
- For the VPN the local ip issued is 172.18.107.236 and remote ip
  issued is 172.18.107.235
- On my ADSL modem I have setup port forwarding on port 1723 TCP to
  172.18.107.238 (mikrotik)

The problem and question is: I am able to access the complete CTWUG range 172.16.0.0/16 except my home range 172.18.107.224/28. I have torched the pptp(VPN) interface and I can see the packets for my local range being forwarded to the device on my local range. There is just no packets returning over the VPN. Any help please.

Comment: The default gateway on the destination network needs to know to forward the return packets to the VPN endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Had to change the ARP on my local ethernet to arp-proxy and change the local vpn proxy to that of my mikrotik router.

Comment: Can you explain the last part, I'm trying to get this working too, what does "local vpn proxy" mean?

Comment: Nevermind, contacted my reseller and they explained that you only need proxy-arp if your vpn clients are sharing the same subnet.. I've been a fool!